# What is the meaning of (marker, i) in this Google Maps APIv3 code?

Tags: javascript, maps

```
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {

                marker.setMap(null);

                }
                })(marker, i));
```

I got this code from the web and it works very well. I am unsure though of the meaning of "(marker, i)" which is at the tail of the function. Can someone explain a bit more about this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to create a new scope.

If you just do:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
});
```

it will fail if `marker` later changes.  This code is probably used in a loop.  However, the `i` is pointless.  It can be simplified to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', (function(marker) {
    return function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
})(marker));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a self-invoking function.

`(marker, i)` is the parameters that are passed when calling the function.